# Adding category filter to CRUD in LARAVEL but it's not showing the filtered category name in Selectbox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am new to Laravel. I was working on a Book CRUD, when I am adding a category filter to my book, it gets filtered successfully but it doesn't show the applied filter in the select box.

I have attached all the required files below, and also please correct me if I am using the wrong approach.

According to me the issue which comes is this: I am passing my category's `id` to the URL and then the page gets refreshed and it shows the first option in the select box.

##### `books.blade.php`

```html
<select onchange="document.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option>Pick a choice!</option>
    <option value={{ route('books.index') }}>All</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ route('books.index', ['category' => $category->id]) }}">
            {{ $category->name}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Everything is working fine but it is just not showing the selected category in the select box. I have already tried to apply a different condition but none worked.

##### `BookController.php`

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if (auth()->user()) {
        if ($request->category == "All") {
            $books = Books::orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->get();
        } elseif ($request->category) {
            $books = Books::orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->where('category_id', $request->category)
                ->get();
        } else {
            $books = Books::orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->get();
        }

        return view("books", ['books' => $books])
            ->with('categories', Category::all());
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

I am also attaching a screenshot in which the category filter name `Ethics` is applied but the selectbox shows `Pick a choice!`.

If I can solve this using AJAX, please write the code for AJAX also.

[image: Category filter applied but not showing in selectbox]

When I apply the category filter to my books I was expecting the filtered category name also to be shown on the select box.

Comment: I think you need to add selected conditon to select the category

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing to the view what category the user selected.

Your view should be like this:

```html
<select>
    <option>Pick a choice!</option>
    <option value="{{ route('books.index') }}">All</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ route('books.index', ['category' => $category->id]) }}" {{ (isset($selected) && $selected === $category->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>
            {{ $category->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

That is one way, it will check if the user has a selected category first asking if the variable `$selected` is present, then it will ask if that value is equal to the category's ID, if it matches, it will add `selected` to the `option` tag, making it automatically selected when the page is finally rendered (this is pure HTML).

So, now edit the controller so we can share that `$selected` value:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if (! auth()->user()) {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    if ($request->category == "All") {
        $books = Books::orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->get();
    } elseif ($request->category) {
        $books = Books::orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('category_id', $request->category)
            ->get();
    } else {
        $books = Books::orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->get();
    }

    return view("books", ['books' => $books])
        ->with('categories', Category::all())
        ->with('selected', $request->category);
}
```

See that I have "beautified" your `if`, if the user is not logged in, redirect (moved it from the bottom to the top), if the user is logged in, we continue with the code.

I have added `->with('selected', $request->category)` on the last `return`, so that one will share the category's ID with the view.

This is one way of doing it!

---

If you are on Laravel 9.x+, you can use [`@selected`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes) like this:

```html
<select>
    <option>Pick a choice!</option>
    <option value="{{ route('books.index') }}">All</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ route('books.index', ['category' => $category->id]) }}" @selected(isset($selected) && $selected === $category->id)>
            {{ $category->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: No sir, It didn't worked out......I am using laravel 10, when I am adding your code, it just changes the filter name in the select box but my category filter is not working.

Comment: Your issue is that you do not have a button to send the FILTER! So you choose whatever you want but hou are never sending your selection to the controller... I am not going to waste time writting that for you when it is a common thing to do and you can find it googling....

Comment: I am sending the value to the controller using onchange in the select, I think that is the issue because it refresh the page

Comment: Yeah, have in mind that is very annoying, changing selection and automatically refreshing the whole page is annoying